# Где поменять карточку товара virtuemart2?

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

Хочу поменять карточку товара, а точнее

```
Старая цена: 12300,00 р
Цена: 6500,00 р
```

Поменять названия Старая цена на Цена, и Цена на Цена со скидкой + прописать стили слова одним цветом цифры другим

и еще где поменять надпись Корзина пуста ?

- вопрос. На главной странице есть модуль НОВИНКИ СКИДКИ АКЦИИ, где можно его править? мне просто надо прописать индивидуальный стиль для него и применять к тайтлу span на каждое слово типо
  НовинкиАКЦИИ

Answer (score 1):

всё в файлах *virtuemart* в каталоге /language, ищите и правьте, UTF-8,  например, Far-ом )
кажется, там же можно и тэги вписывать (**Цена...**)
стили и т.п. лучше менять в соотв.подкаталогах для компонентов и модулей текущей темы. обычный функционал для joomla

Comment: а вот На главной странице есть модуль НОВИНКИ СКИДКИ АКЦИИ, где можно его править? если я пишу это просто в default.php то он отображается на всех страницах

Comment: default.php где?
в тройке в модулях вижу "VM - Featured products" - соответственно есть каталог mod_... /modules и, возможно, в тема/html(кажется)/modules . но здесь правится "навсегда". если только стили, лучше создавать модуль, и использовать фунциональность последней вкладки в этом модуле "Доп.параметры" (суффиксы, классы...).
 пишу по памяти, к сожалению